# jQuery "hover" function is not working in FireFox over <area> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, area

Explanation of my code:

I have 3 images that are constantly scrolling left.  When an image gets too far left, it gets placed all the way to the right again, creating a nice transition effect.

The images are mapped using  tags, and when you mouse over an image, the scrolling stops, and a popover shows up over the specific area of the image.

In Chrome and Safari this works, but in FireFox, the hover function does not register for the  tags.  What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
var custom_style = 'night'; // set this to day or night, and then set_style to "true" to activate it
var set_style = true; // When this is false, it uses your computer's time
var speed = 2; // number of pixels moved left every 50 milliseconds

paused = false;
area = null; 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var style = "day"
    if (date.getHours() >= 17 || date.getHours() <= 5 || (set_style && custom_style == 'night')){
        style="night";
        $('#day_sign2').hide();
        $('#night_sign').show();
        $('.customarea').addClass('customareaNight');
    }else{
        $('#container').css( 'backgroundImage', '0 !important' );
        $('#container').addClass('night_container');
    }
    setInterval(wells_fancy_slider, 50);
    $('area').css('z-index', '5000');
    t = null;

    $('area').hover(function() { // this is not registering in FF
        $('.customarea').hide();
        paused = true;
        area = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.custom' + area).show();
        alert(area);
        console.log('.custom' + area);
        t = setTimeout(custom_mouseover, 5000);
    }, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.customarea').hide();
            paused = false;
        }, 2500)
    });

    if (style == 'day'){
        $('#container').css('background-color', 'white');
        $('.night').hide();
    }else{
        $('.day').hide();
    }

})

function custom_mouseover() {
    clearInterval(t)
}

function wells_fancy_slider() {
    if (!paused) {
        if (parseInt($('.pic1').css('left')) < -2770) {
            $('.pic1').css('left', '5586');
        }
        if (parseInt($('.pic2').css('left')) < -2770) {
            $('.pic2').css('left', '5586');
        }
        if (parseInt($('.pic3').css('left')) < -2770) {
            $('.pic3').css('left', '5586');
        }
        $('.pic1, .pic2, .pic3').css('left', '-=' + speed);
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wells_slider.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="wells_slider.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:absolute; width: 15%; z-index: 2000; float: left; height: 100%; left:0px; background-color:black;"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute; width: 15%; z-index: 2000; float: right; height: 100%; right:0px; background-color:black;"></div>

        <div id="container">
            <div style="width: 100%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;position: relative;height: 50px;">
                <img id="day_sign" src="img/day_sign.png" />
                <img id="day_sign2" src="img/day_sign2.png" />
                <img id="night_sign" src="img/night_sign.png" style="display:none;" />
            </div>
            <div id="pic_container">
                <img class="pic1 day" src="img/LMday.png" usemap="img_map" border="0" width="2798" height="450" alt="" />
                <img class="pic2 day" src="img/LMday.png" usemap="img_map" border="0" width="2798" height="450" alt="" />
                <img class="pic3 day" src="img/LMday.png" usemap="img_map" border="0" width="2798" height="450" alt="" />

                <img class="pic1 night" src="img/LMnight.png" usemap="img_map" border="0" width="2798" height="450" alt="" />
                <img class="pic2 night" src="img/LMnight.png" usemap="img_map" border="0" width="2798" height="450" alt="" />
                <img class="pic3 night" src="img/LMnight.png" usemap="img_map" border="0" width="2798" height="450" alt="" />

                <map id="img_map" name="img_map">
                    <area id="area1" shape="rect" coords="3,69,413,445"  alt="1" title="1"    />
                    <area id="area2" shape="rect" coords="413,73,692,443"  alt="2" title="2"    />
                    <area id="area3" shape="rect" coords="692,91,919,440" alt="3" title="3"    />
                    <area id="area4" shape="rect" coords="917,102,1135,440"  alt="4" title="4"    />
                    <area id="area5" shape="rect" coords="1134,103,1363,441" alt="5" title="5"    />
                    <area id="area6" shape="rect" coords="1360,107,1591,438"  alt="6" title="6"    />
                    <area id="area7" shape="rect" coords="1589,96,1872,438"  alt="7" title="7"    />
                    <area id="area8" shape="rect" coords="1871,100,2072,439" alt="8" title="8"    />
                    <area id="area9" shape="rect" coords="2072,116,2272,436" alt="9" title="9"    />
                    <area id="area10" shape="rect" coords="2270,70,2597,433" alt="10" title="10"    />
                    <area id="area11" shape="rect" coords="2595,78,2784,430" alt="11" title="11"    />
                </map>
                <div class="p_container popup_container1 pic1">
                    <a href="http://www.wellsjohnston.com"><div class="customarea customarea1" >
                            Some Text
                        </div></a>
                    <div class="customarea customarea2" style="left:400px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea3" style="left:690px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea4" style="left:912px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea5" style="left:1132px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea6" style="left:1357px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea7" style="left:1585px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea8" style="left:1870px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea9" style="left:2070px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea10" style="left:2265px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea11" style="left:2595px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="p_container popup_container2 pic2">
                    <div class="customarea customarea1" >
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea2" style="left:400px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea3" style="left:690px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea4" style="left:917px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea5" style="left:1132px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea6" style="left:1357px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea7" style="left:1585px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea8" style="left:1870px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea9" style="left:2070px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea10" style="left:2265px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea11" style="left:2595px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="p_container popup_container3 pic3">
                    <div class="customarea customarea1" >
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea2" style="left:400px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea3" style="left:690px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea4" style="left:917px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea5" style="left:1132px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea6" style="left:1357px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea7" style="left:1585px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea8" style="left:1870px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea9" style="left:2070px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea10" style="left:2265px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                    <div class="customarea customarea11" style="left:2595px;">
                        Some Text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you recreate the problem using jsfiddle.net or provide a link to your site?

Comment: It's not hosted and I can't get it to look good on jsfiddle, but I could email you a zip file with everything.  Or is there temp storage online that is easy?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like interacting with the 'area' tag. Try adding a class to each area tag and put the classname into your jQuery instead of 'area'.

Comment: Great suggestion, I'll try right now

Comment: Also I don't think the area tags should be self closed. IIRC they don't require closing at all. Not sure if that would be an issue with your problem though.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still didn't work :-\ any other ideas??

Comment: Really hard to diagnose without a working example. Maybe try mouseenter instead of hover? http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: mouseenter didn't work either.  I think it has to do with z-indexing and one div covering the others or something. Is there any way I can put a .zip of my source files somewhere you can see them?

Comment: Here is the source code download http://temp-share.com/show/YgFHjkPEy

Comment: Had a look but can't really figure out what's going on. One more random suggestion would be to ditch the image map, substitute the image tags for 'a' tags and insert the images on them as background images. Hopefully Firefox (and all other browsers) would be happy with the 'a' tags. You could also just place a span inside the 'a' tags with the hover bg/text.

Comment: So you're suggesting splitting up the image into 11 separate images instead of 1 image with area tags?  I really don't want to do that since it already works this way in chrome/safari

Comment: Ah well, sorry I couldn't figure it out. I'm sure it must be something simple!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out.

On your image tags you need to place a hash tag before the map name.

```
<img class="pic1 day" src="img/LMday.png" usemap="#img_map" border="0" width="2798" height="450" alt="" />
```